# Yocto Add own Header and Lib file's to sdk

Tags: sdk, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I want to add `.h` and `.lib` files to my own created recipe to the SDK.
I use CMake to build my lib's, with the SDK I can build it.
My recipe name is `served`. (I want to add the `served` https://github.com/meltwater/served as my own recipe).
in my `served_0.1.bb` file I added the following:

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk" 
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "nativesdk-served"
```

in the `layer.conf` I added:

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " served "
```

When I start to create my SDK with

```
bitbake core-image-base -c populate_sdk
```

> ERROR: core-image-base-1.0-r0 do_populate_sdk: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/3.2.4/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/3.2.4/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/3.2.4/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux --setopt=logdir=/home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo --nogpgcheck install packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-standalone-sdk-target psplash-raspberrypi run-postinsts served target-sdk-provides-dummy' returned 1:
> DNF version: 4.2.23
> cachedir: /home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/sdk/image/opt/poky/3.2.4/sysroots/cortexa72-poky-linux/var/cache/dnf
> Added oe-repo repo from /home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/oe-sdk-repo
> User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
> repo: using cache for: oe-repo
> oe-repo: using metadata from Sun 06 Jun 2021 03:50:26 PM UTC.
> Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Sun 06 Jun 2021 03:50:26 PM UTC.
> --> Starting dependency resolution
> --> Finished dependency resolution
> Error:
> Problem: conflicting requests
>
> - nothing provides nativesdk-served needed by served-1.0+git0+2eb36b83fa-r0.cortexa72 (try to add '--skip-broken' to
>   skip uninstallable packages)
>
> ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
> /home/yocto/videoMon/build/tmp/work/raspberrypi4_64-poky-linux/core-image-base/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_populate_sdk.27092
> ERROR: Task
> (/home/yocto/videoMon/meta/recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb:do_populate_sdk)
> failed with exit code '1'

Have anyone has an an idea?

Bests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a recipe for `served` which compiles without errors.

The step to add served `.h` and `lib` files to sdk is to add below line to local.conf

```
TOOLCHAIN_TARGET_TASK_append = " served "
```

And then run command

```
bitbake core-image-base -c populate_sdk
```

**The lines below in your served recipe are causing errors and are not needed for SDK generation. Please remove them and try building your image again.**

```
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk" 
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "nativesdk-served"
```